# MVVMCross Field Binding CodeBehind

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm trying to bind the EventArgs result of a MapLongClicked event to a property "Location" on the ViewModel on Xamarin Forms, using GoogleMaps nuget package.
The problem is that I can only access those EventArgs in XAML Code behind.
As I'm using MVVMCross, I've found [something](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/fieldbinding) about field binding, but it's not for code behind.
My MapPage looks like this right now:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MapPage : MvxContentPage
{
    public MapPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        map.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;

        map.MapLongClicked += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //((MapViewModel)map.BindingContext).Location = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Spatial.Point(e.Point.Longitude, e.Point.Latitude);
            var pin = new Pin
            {
                Type = PinType.SearchResult,
                Position = new Position(e.Point.Latitude, e.Point.Longitude),
                Label = string.Format(e.Point.Latitude.ToString("0.000") + " / " + e.Point.Longitude.ToString("0.000"))
            };
            map.Pins.Add(pin);
        };

    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<mvx:MvxContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
    xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps"
    xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:XamFormsMaps.Core.Behaviors;assembly=XamFormsMaps.Core"
    x:Class="XamFormsMaps.Core.Pages.MapPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <maps:Map 
               x:Name="map"
               WidthRequest="320" 
               HeightRequest="200"
               IsShowingUser="true"
               MapType="Hybrid">

                <maps:Map.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:MapBehavior ItemsSource="{Binding Parkings}" />
                </maps:Map.Behaviors>
            </maps:Map>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</mvx:MvxContentPage>
```

I've tried the commented option but it's giving me a casting error, so I haven't got more ideas.

Does anyone know how can I send a variable from XAML code behind to a ViewModel?

Comment: Does the map has a `MapLongClicked` property on XAML ?

Comment: Yeeees! It does @FabriBertani

Comment: did you try bind that property with a command on the viewmodel ? like `MapLongClick="{Binding SomeCommand}"`

Comment: I've tried but I don't know if it's possible neither how to get the EventArgs from that command on the ViewModel

Comment: show us your xaml code too

Comment: You get casting error because `map.bindingcontext` is not `MapViewModel`?

Comment: I have added the XAML to this post.   I don't know why but now the casting is working (map.BindingContext is MapViewModel) and I didn't change anything :/ So problem solved, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
((MapViewModel)map.BindingContext).Location = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Spatial.Point(e.Point.Longitude, e.Point.Latitude);
        var pin = new Pin
```

Make sure the map.BindingContext is MapViewModel at runtime.